# How to run RequireJS optimizer via Sublime Text 2 Build System

Tags: requirejs, sublimetext2

My build config looks like this.

```
{
  "cmd": ["node r.js -o app.build.js"],
  "working_dir": "$project_path"
}
```

The Sublime error log looks like this:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'node r.js -o app.build.js']]
[dir:  /Users/janjarfalk/Desktop/Projects/Template]
[path: /Users/janjarfalk/Desktop/Projects/Template]
[Finished]
```

And the Sublime console looks like this:

```
Running node r.js -o app.build.js
```

If I run "node r.js -o app.build.js" in "/Users/janjarfalk/Desktop/Projects/Template" in the Terminal it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The ST2 [docs](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) show the cmd value should be the same command but split into an array of strings, so in your config it would look like ["node", "r.js", "-o", "app.build.js"]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my build

**Step to build working**

step 1 : install node for cmd

of course you will need node js to complie the r.js

step 2 : create a project

menu --> project --> save

step 3 : create r.js build file

Save path just outside of the project folder so that it dont get mix up with project files

i do a .../build/app.build.js

where the build folder also contain r.js

step 4 : create a build plugin for sublime text

Menu --> Tools --> Build system --> new build system

```
{
    "cmd": ["node", "r.js", "-o", "app.build.js"], 
    "working_dir" : "${project_path:${folder}}/../build"
}
```

save as RJS.sublime-build

Note that i use ${project_path:${folder}} instead of a absolute path so that i dont have to create a new buildtool for each project just keep the same relative path